# XPages: dojox.form.HorizontalRangeSlider

Tags: dojo, slider, xpages

I have Domino 9.0.1 and dojo 1.9.4
Can i use HorizontalRangeSlider? 
When i trying require this control, load empty javasript file.
Example:

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:dojoModule name="dojox/form/HorizontalRangeSlider"></xp:dojoModule>
</xp:this.resources>
<div id="hrSlider" dojoType="dojox.form.HorizontalRangeSlider"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but just declaring a div with the dojoType isn't sufficient.

See the [Dojo documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/HorizontalSlider.html#dijit-form-horizontalslider) if you want to do it manually. You'll either need declarative code to set the properties according to what you want, or programmatic code.

Alternatively, use the Dojo Horizontal Slider control, as documented in XPages Extension Library book. The book also highlights why the control was added - to allow a single component on the page which comprised all the properties required by the slider's various HTML elements.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer. But you are sure, what your answer about Horizontal **Range** Slider?

Comment: dojox.form.HorizontalRangeSlider doesn't appear to exist, only dojox.form.RangeSlider. Here is the correct Dojo documentation https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/form/RangeSlider.html#dojox-form-rangeslider. Declarative code still needs properties defining for the div, including whether it's a horizontal range slider.

There is no Extension Library component for the range slider. In the onChange (as in the example in Ext Lib book), using "#{id:myInputText}" in the dojo.byId() function you'll be able to push the value to an XPages Edit Box component